shutdown does not work (caused by wifi)
I have described my problem in another topic:
shutdown does not work - rebooting
The laptop will shut down and then boot again - but only if the wifi module in BIOS (uefi) is enabled. So my temporary solution is using the laptop with disabled wifi and using an ethernet cable connection instead. No more problems with unwanted reboots.
How can I find out what exactly is the wifi problem about? Someone suggested me that it may be ACPI issue, but where should I be looking for details?
The laptop is HP Probook 440 G9 and the onboard wifi module is Realtek RTL8852BE.
My Ubuntu is the latest 24.04.01 LTS

Try echo "options rtw89_pci disable_aspm_l1=y disable_aspm_l1ss=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8852.conf reboot

So what this command does is just creating a config file with some options? Tried that and it didn't work. Unless I have to link it somewhere or do anything else...

Yes, it creates a config file that sets module options as suggested by Larry Finger as he had this to say https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89?tab=readme-ov-file#option-configuration

Is Fast Startup enabled in the BIOS?

This issue can be fixed by this commit. Now my repository contains a rtw89 driver with it. Do you want to give it a try?
# install the packages needed for compilation
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git

# clone the rtw89 driver
git clone https://github.com/a5a5aa555oo/rtw89

# build and install it via dkms
cd rtw89
sudo dkms install $PWD

# reboot your system
reboot

